# List supervised students on website?

Tags: supervision, website

As a phd student I am wondering whether or not to list supervised students on personal website (I am tending to a "yes"). Would you only list masters/bachelor student or also other student projects?

I am also not sure, how much information is reasonable. Just the name/title? Abstract? Current position?

Are there any legal issues I should keep in mind?

Comment: When reading your question, I thought of a projects list that also might include the students' names, but "Current position?" made me wonder: Are you thinking about a projects list, as well, or are you rather referring to a list of supervised students with a remark about what they did? i.e. what is the intended focus and target audience of the list?

Comment: Also, you may want to specify whether your website would be the only way to obtain the respective information. I always listed Bachelor and Master theses I supervised with the name of the student, but only because I knew these would be publicly listed by the library, anyway. Otherwise, privacy concerns might be relevant.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I was thinking of a list like: marc smith, The influence of x to y (master's thesis), currently working at companyX; Target audience would be other potential students (and possibly future collaborators/other phd students)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper the information is publicity available during the students stay, but removed after the students finish their project

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment on the legal issues: I'm not a lawyer and you don't specify which country you are in.

In any case, I'd ask them a written consent before listing *any* information. In particular:

1. In the consent form, report clearly which items are going to be listed.
2. In the consent form, specify the time frame along which you plan to show that information.
3. In the consent form, specify that they can withdraw the consent any time and you will oblige.
4. I'd list only name, title and possibly abstract.
5. I wouldn't list the current position because it is typically subject to change without notice.